# How do I remove html character &gt in vba innertext

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

So I'm trying to pull data from https://stt.wiki/wiki/Alcohol, and I'm iterating through table, tr, then td to get down where I want to be.  I'm using the innerText property because the html sometimes interrupts phrases I want to keep together.

When I hit places in that page that have >>, innerText displays them as >>

I have tried doing:

```
Dim iTds As IHTMLElementCollection
Set iTds = .document.getElementsByTagName("td")
For k = 0 To iTds.Length - 1
    Debug.Print Trim(Replace(iTds(k).innerText, "&gt;", ""))
    Debug.Print Trim(Replace(iTds(k).innerText, ">", ""))
    Debug.Print Trim(Replace(iTds(k).innerText, ChrW(32), ""))
next k
```

All of those Debug.Print statements show the >> characters, meaning none of them replaced anything.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, the

```
Debug.Print Trim(Replace(iTds(k).innerText, ">", ""))
```

line did work... after I could've sworn it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `Chr()` and `Asc()` might be your friends in such cases.

- [Chr](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function) - Returns a String containing the character associated with the specified character code
- [Asc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/asc-function) - Returns an Integer representing the character code corresponding to the first letter in a string.

Imagine you have a string like this:

```
a = "My place#"
```

You want to replace `"#"` with `""`, but you don't know what to type in your `Replace()` function for the char `#`.
Then you would:

- Get the character code with `Asc(Right(a,1))` >> `35`
- Use this value in `Chr(35)` to use the good char in the `Replace` function:

  ```
  a = Replace(a, Chr(35), "")
  ```

Comment: That was one of the ones I tried.  Well, ChrW instead of Chr, but still.

Comment: @TulsaNewbie then please post a sample of the string you get in `.innerText` and are unable to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Those >> are for the tooltip class elements. You could remove those from the html and also do a test that the td innerText <> vbNullString for a tidier output. Depends whether you want the tool tip info.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetYahooData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, js As String, iTds As IHTMLElementCollection, temp As String, k As Long, i As Long
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://stt.wiki/wiki/Alcohol"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        js = "var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');" & _
             "while(classes[0]) {" & _
             "classes[0].parentNode.removeChild(classes[0]);" & _
             "}"

        .document.parentWindow.execScript js

        Set iTds = .document.getElementsByTagName("td"): i = 1
        For k = 0 To iTds.Length - 1
            temp = iTds(k).innerText
            If temp <> vbNullString Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = temp
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Otherwise, you could optimize your existing code by using css type selector and type functions

```
Dim iTds As Object, temp As String
Set iTds = .document.querySelectorAll("td")
For k = 0 To iTds.Length - 1
    temp = Trim$(Replace$(iTds(k).innerText, ">", ""))
    If temp <> vbNullString Then Debug.Print temp
Next k
```

Comment: Let me know what you think